# What should I do to find the last occurrence of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am currently taking the Udacity CS101 course (I am a complete beginner). Here is the last quiz of lesson 2:
 Define a procedure, find_last, that takes as input two strings, a search string and a target string,and returns the last position in the search string where the target string appears, or -1 if there are no occurences.

Example: find_last('aaaa', 'a') returns 3.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
    def find_last(s,t):
        i=s.find(t)
        if i==-1:
            return -1
        else:
            while True:
                return (s.find(t,i+1))
                i=i+1
            return s.find(t)
    print(find_last('he is','he')
```

This code does not work for most test cases. For example, here I am expecting an output of 0, but I am getting an output of -1 ('he' definitely exists in 'he is',so the output cannot be -1). Please help.

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Counting from the right

Search from the end string. You can use `str.rfind()` for this:

```
def find_last(s, t, cheat=True):
   if cheat:
       return s.rfind(t)
   else:
       for i in range(len(s), len(t) - 1, -1):
            if s[i - len(t):i] == t:
                return i-len(t)                
       return -1  

print(find_last('he is he', 'he'))
```

Output

```
6
```

### Counting from the left

If you stick to your algo which counts from the left, you can do the following:

```
def find_last(s,t):
    i = -1
    while True:
        new_i = s.find(t, i + 1)
        if new_i == -1:
            return i
        i = new_i
    return i
print(find_last('aaaa','a'))
```

Output

```
3
```

Comment: The `cheat=True` is a nice touch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But could you please tell me what's wrong with my code? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @ABRARRAKIN ignoring the indentation, your `while` statements returns immediately during the first iteration. If there's only one occurrence, it would have been found in the first line of your function. If there are two occurrences, it will return second occurrence (which is correct). If there are more than two however, it will still return the second occurrence since `str.find()` only returns the first occurrence from the left.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but how should I modify my code to perform more than 2 checks?

Comment: @ABRARRAKIN You have to return only when `str.find()` returns `-1`. I updated my answer if you want to check it out

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please explain why the value of i was initialized to -1?

Comment: @ABRARRAKIN Two reasons, 1st is so you can say the default value is "not found" so you set it to `-1`; 2nd reason and arguably more important is so the line `new_i = s.find(t, i + 1)` starts with the index `0` since `-1 + 1 = 0`

Comment: Great to hear @ABRARRAKIN. If any of these answers helped answer your question, feel free to mark the question as resolved. To know more, check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

As this is a course, I won't give you an answer. Here is something to consider.

> Suppose our string is = "This sentence is a sentence"
>
> Suppose our search term is = "sent"

If you start from the front  of the string, you will have to iterate through a large portion of the string. What if you reverse your search term, and search from the back of the string?

> Now your search term is "tnes"

If you start from the back of the string, you will be using a for loop with a negative increment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But could you please tell me what's wrong with my code? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Try to run your code in debug mode with breakpoints to understand why your code is failing. With your example, you find "t" in "s". It finds it at location 0. Since i is not -1, it goes to the else case and calls find and passes the string after " is". Now in this instance of find it does not find it, so it returns -1. Hence your result is -1. It should also be noted that with your current code, you will only perform 2 checks from the start of the code. So for the code "he he he", you will find the second he, but not the third.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
try:
    string ="Hello WorldHello World"
    query = "hey"
    index = string.lower().rindex(query.lower())
except ValueError:
    index = -1
print(index)
```

Output:

```
-1
```

When query was "hello", gave `11`

This works even if the string-case is different. 
Python string method rindex() returns the last index where the substring str is found, `or raises an exception if no such index exists`.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rindex.htm

Answer (score 1):

In keeping with your approach of starting at the front and working through the string and assuming you don't just want to use the build-in `rfind()`, you can loop with `index()`. It takes a second parameter that tells it where to start looking. This will raise an exception when it can't find the substring, which you can catch and use as a way to end your function. This makes it very succinct and pythonic. You just set the initial index to -1 and update it until it raises that exception:

```
def find_last(s,t):
    ind = -1
    while True:
        try:
            ind = s.index(t, ind + 1)  
        except ValueError:
            return ind

s = "this_is_a_test"
find_last(s, 'is')
# 4
find_last(s, 't')
# 13
find_last(s, 'z')
# -1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But could you please tell me what's wrong with my code? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @ABRARRAKIN the main issue in your code is that you `return` immediately after the `while` — there's no way for that loop to run. You need to test if `find()` returns `-1` and then break out of the loop.